# How to read input two dimensional array value in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a form to add many contacts in html the input is two dimensional array here is the form:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="account[0][name]" placeholder="Name"  autocomplete="off" />
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="account[0][email]" placeholder="Email"  autocomplete="off" />
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="account[0][mobile]" placeholder="Mobile"  autocomplete="off" />

<input class="form-control" type="text" name="account[1][name]" placeholder="Name"  autocomplete="off" />
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="account[1][email]" placeholder="Email"  autocomplete="off" />
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="account[1][mobile]" placeholder="Mobile"  autocomplete="off" />
```

I am trying to get the value using jqueryI tried the following, it returns the value but i want to return an input value of account name or account email or account mobile

```
 $('input[name^="account"]').each(function() {
                console.log($(this).val());
        });
```

Comment: What do you mean "return an exact input"? You want what's in the string in the second brackets?

Comment: I meant like to return the value of account name or account email or account mobile

Comment: If you want the value of the input, meaning what the user inputs, then your code works. Please be more specific.

Comment: I want to get the value of account[0][name],  account[1][name] ,  account[2][name] ,  account[3][name] ,  account[4][name]

Answer (score 1):

<del>That is not `value` that is an attribute called `placeholder` so you should use `.attr()` method instead:</del>
<del>console.log($(this).attr('placeholder'));</del>

*but i want to return an input value of account name or account email or account mobile*  for this you can use `.serializeArray();`

```js
$('pre').html(JSON.stringify($('.form-control').serializeArray(), 0, 3));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre></pre>

<input class="form-control" type="text" name="account[0][name]" placeholder="Name"  autocomplete="off" />
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="account[0][email]" placeholder="Email"  autocomplete="off" />
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="account[0][mobile]" placeholder="Mobile"  autocomplete="off" />

<input class="form-control" type="text" name="account[1][name]" placeholder="Name"  autocomplete="off" />
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="account[1][email]" placeholder="Email"  autocomplete="off" />
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="account[1][mobile]" placeholder="Mobile"  autocomplete="off" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [starts with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and [ends with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) attribute selectors:

```
$('[name^="account"][name$="[name]"]')
```

Would select all elements where the name starts with `account` and ends with `[name]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
$('input[name^="account"]').each(function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control" type="text" value="test" name="account[0][name]" placeholder="Name" autocomplete="off" />
<input class="form-control" type="text" value="test@gmail.com" name="account[0][email]" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off" />
<input class="form-control" type="text" value="1234568790" name="account[0][mobile]" placeholder="Mobile" autocomplete="off" />

<input class="form-control" type="text" value="test2" name="account[1][name]" placeholder="Name" autocomplete="off" />
<input class="form-control" type="text" value="test2@gmail.com" name="account[1][email]" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off" />
<input class="form-control" type="text" value="3216549870" name="account[1][mobile]" placeholder="Mobile" autocomplete="off" />
```