# How to change value of html input text box name with multidimenal name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm have some values to fill in the text box. In input text box. It contains multidimensional array so how can i set value using jquery.

```
    <input 
        type="text"
        id="kvtabform1-1-score" 
        class="form-control" 
        name="kvTabForm1[1][Score]" 
        autocomplete="off"/>
```

Comment: Please show what you tried implementing

Comment: i want to fill value to the text box using jquery, But it contains multi-dimensional array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35696140/how-to-read-input-two-dimensional-array-value-in-jquery

Comment: `$("input:text").val(kvTabForm1[1][Score]);` try this if this works

Comment: Why not take the a tour to the world of [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) ..? Makes good for @ShubhamJain too ...

Answer (score 0):

Using [starts with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```js
$('[name^="kvTabForm1"]').each(function() {
    $(this).val('hello')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="kvtabform1-1-score" class="form-control" name="kvTabForm1[1][Score]" autocomplete="off">
```